# Maintain Scroll Position BETWEEN TWO PAGES ASP.NET

Tags: scroll, position

I want to maintain the Scroll Position between two pages. I have a Page A which has many reports, when user clicks a report, user will be redirected to Page B where the report will be opened to make the changes. After submitting changes, user will be redirected to Page A. Here the problem is, showing the top of the page but I want to show the page at the previous position.

I have tried using this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;  but this is working only on the same page but not between the different pages.

I really need to fix this, please give me your thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably give every link/report on page A an anchor.

So, for each report you would hide an `id` attribute somewhere - say the title, so it would be something like `<h3 id="report42">Report 42</h3>`. Then when you go back from page B, instead of going to `www.example.com/pageA.html`, you go to `www.example.com/pageA.html#report42`. This will open the page with the scrollbar at wherever the `report42` id is found.

Comment: Page B has only one report not all reports. After making changes to that report, user will be redirected to Page A. I didn't understand "The simplest thing to do might be to give every link/report on both pages a target, such as example.com/pageB#report42."

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood that part. Changed answer and elaborated.